# Getting error while using the MessagePattern to communicate between microservices

Tags: tcp, nestjs, tcpclient, nestjs-typeorm, nestjs-microservice

There are two services in my application. First one is customer management service and api gateway. Customer management service use nestjs and postgreSQL as the database with typeorm. In the API gateway I also use nestjs and I send request from postman to api and then api should communicate the message to the customer management service. This error gets when I use the Get() in the api gatewat to pass customer is as Params. I used the TCP as the transport layer as well.

How to fix this and retrieve the data using Get() from the customer service using api gateway ? Thank you!

This is the code of the app.controller.ts in api gateway I used,

```
import {Body, Controller, Get, Inject, Param, Post} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { RegisterCustomerDTO } from './models/customerModel';

@Controller('customer')
export class ApprController {
  constructor(
    @Inject('CUSTOMER_MANAGEMENT') private customerClient: ClientProxy,
  ) {}

  @Get(':id')
  async getCustomer(@Param('id') id: any){
    return this.customerClient.send({cmd: 'GET_CUSTOMER'}, id);
  }
}
```

This is the code of the app.controller.ts of the customer management,

```
import {Controller, Get, Param} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MessagePattern, Payload } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { CustomerDTO } from './dto/CustomerDTO';
import { Customer } from './customer.entity';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly customerManagement: AppService) {}

  @MessagePattern({cmd: 'GET_CUSTOMER'})
  async getCustomer(@Param('id') id : any): Promise<Customer>{
    return await this.customerManagement.findCustomer(id);
  }
}
```

This is the code of app.service.ts of customer service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Customer } from './customer.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CustomerDTO } from './dto/CustomerDTO';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Customer)
    private readonly customerRepository: Repository<Customer>,
  ) {}

  async findCustomer(id: any): Promise<Customer | null>{
    return await this.customerRepository.findOneById(id);
  }
}
```

When I pass a request through postman like below,

**http://localhost:3000/customer/1**

I get this error in the terminal of the api gateway,

**There is no matching event handler defined in the remote service**

Also I got this from the postman,

**{
"message": "Cannot GET /customer/getCustomer/1",
"error": "Not Found",
"statusCode": 404
}*